# React Bootstrap Radio Form w onChange

Tags: reactjs, forms, radio-button, react-bootstrap

Apologies if there are similar answers out there, but for this specific use case (i.e. using React Bootstrap and radio buttons) I have been finding some odd issues. The documentation isn't helpful and there doesn't seem to be any great examples on the internet. The code below "works" but is through brute force and there is undoubtedly an easier way.

```
  const [isNumber1, setIsNumber1] = useState(false)
  const [isNumber2, setIsNumber2] = useState(false)
  const [isNumber3, setIsNumber3] = useState(false)

  const radioFunc1 = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    if (isNumber1 == false) {
      setIsNumber1(true)
      setIsNumber2(false)
      setIsNumber3(false)
    }
  }

  const radioFunc2 = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    if (isNumber2 == false) {
      setIsNumber2(true)
      setIsNumber1(false)
      setIsNumber3(false)
    }
  }

  const radioFunc3 = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation()
    if (isNumber3 == false) {
      setIsNumber3(true)
      setIsNumber1(false)
      setIsNumber2(false)
    }
  }

<Form.Group controlId='isNumber1' className='NumbersGroup'>
  <Form.Check
    inline
    label='Radio 1'
    checked={isNumber1}
    type='radio'
    name='numberRadio'
    onChange={radioFunc1}
  />
</Form.Group>
<Form.Group controlId='isNumber2' className='NumbersGroup'>
  <Form.Check
    inline
    label='Radio 2'
    checked={isNumber2}
    type='radio'
    name='numberRadio'
    onChange={radioFunc2}
  />
</Form.Group>
<Form.Group controlId='isNumber3' className='NumbersGroup'>
  <Form.Check
    inline
    label='Radio 3'
    checked={isNumber3}
    type='radio'
    name='numberRadio'
    onChange={radioFunc3}
  />
</Form.Group>
```